# NoClassDef error on Gingerbread

Tags: android, database, android-2.3-gingerbread

I am getting a `NoClassDefFoundError` thrown from users of devices with Gingerbread and lower OS only. When the user clicks a button to view a list view populated with data from SQLite:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: mooney.rotundalaboratoryusermanual.ViewListOfTests
at mooney.rotundalaboratoryusermanual.MainMenu.onClick(MainMenu.java:334)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2532)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9308)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4293)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The trace refers to a `listactivity` but not sure why can't find the class....

Comment: mooney appears nowhere in the SDK documentation. Is this a package you wrote or imported?

Comment: Yes mooney.rotundausermanual is a package name I created

Comment: Ok, in that case, would you post the involved code and show the line where the exception occurs? It would be really helpful

Comment: I'll come back with the code-thanks